# Generalize XML parsing in r

Tags: xml, r

I have a number of lines in an r script that look as follows:

```
#Type
resultlist=xmlSApply(productlist,function (x) xmlValue(x[["Type"]]))
types=data.frame(resultlist)
names(types)="Type"
#Ratings
resultlist=xmlSApply(productlist,function (x) xmlValue(x[["Ratings"]][["HighestScore"]]))
score=data.frame(as.numeric(resultlist))
names(score)="Score"
```

How can I generalize this into a function of form namedframe=f([[..]][...]],convertToNumeric)?

I can see the convert to numberic bool easily but I'm not sure how to do the [[..]][[..]] argument when there could potentially be multiple levels and the number of levels is unknown.

Google and a search of stackoverflow were not instructive.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What I want the function to do is somehow given a list of names of XML nodes to follow, do xmlSApply with a defined function (x) xmlValue(...function (x) **LIST GOES HERE**) but I'm not sure syntatically how to do that